# How to match stream against white-list and black-list?

Tags: shell, grep

How can I duplicate a pipe stream (output from another program) so that for every line, I can check whether it matches independent regular expressions (ideally, reuse a `grep` command with options like `-i` etc.) but process results of each expression separately?

I want to define exit code from my `check` function as follows:

- no line in stream matches `blacklist`; AND
- at least one line in stream matches `whitelist`

I want to process lines in memory without storing them to file, report exit code and pass original stream to another program using pipes (logging `whitelist` matches to `stderr` or elsewhere would be useful too).

Usage would look like:

```
fetch-big-stream | check whitelist blacklist | cat
exitcode=$?
```

where `fork` duplicates lines, `whitelist` and `blacklist` are functions and `check` passess copy of stream to each separately and terminates once exitcode can be determined before `EOF`. There is also a problem with `|` implementation that does not propagate non-zero code.

Comment: This would me _much_ easier to understand if you showed the actual commands you use. Are you looking through one file or many?

Answer (score 3):

Just use '-f' and '-v' with grep:

```
$ cat white
foo
bar
$ cat black
baz
$ cat input
foo
foo baz
foo bar
baz

$ grep -f white input | grep -v -f black
foo
foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is report files that contain at least one of the patterns in `good.txt` and none of those in `bad.txt`. If you want to do this for a single file, it's trivial:

```
grep -Ff good.txt file | grep -vFf bad.txt
```

If you want to find all files in a directory that match the criteria, you could do something like this (note that it will also match `good.txt` if that's in the same directory):

```
grep -lFf good.txt * | xargs -I{} grep -lvFf bad.txt {}
```

You can fine tune it some more by using `find`. For example, avoid matching `good.txt`:

```
find . -type f -not -name good.txt -exec grep -lFf good.txt {} \; | 
 xargs -I{} grep -l a {}
```